Is the following proof logically sound?
I want to prove the following statement:
Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$, $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$. Then exists $ξ\in(a, b)$, $f^{'}(ξ)=0$.
Here is a sketch of my proof:
Define $f(a)=f(b)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$, then $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$. Together with our given we get by Rolle's Theorem that $\exists$ $ξ\in(a, b)$, $f^{'}(ξ)=0$.
Now since changing the value of $f$ at the endpoints $x=a$ and $x=b$ does not change the function's outputs on the open interval $(a, b)$, it follows that our desired result holds regardless of how the function is defined at $x=a$, $x=b$.

The last paragraph is a bit of a strange addition, you conclude the conclusion of the theorem right before it. Why do you feel the need to add this paragraph?

@Carlyle Since I ascribed specific values to f(a) and f(b), whereas the question itself doesn't say anything about that, so I thought I should explicitly address that the conclusion still holds even if the values of f at the endpoints aren't f(a) and f(b) resp.

This got too long for a comment, and I find it interesting that I originally overlooked a subtlety, which may be instructive to you
Here is a revised, and shorter version of your proof.

Define the function $g$ on $[a,b]$ so that $g(x)=f(x)$ on $(a,b)$ and $$g(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$$ and $$g(b)=\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$$
Then $g$ is continuous on the closed interval and differentiable on the open interval, hence there exists an $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that $g'(\xi) = 0$. But since $f=g$ on a neighbourhood of $\xi$, we get that $f'(\xi)=0$, which is what we wanted to prove

You correctly point out that there is an unresolved assumption when you reach this conclusion in your proof, in this proof, there is no such assumption. The difference being that I defined a new function $g$, and argued about that, whereas you did something that doesn't really make sense, i.e. defining a function outside it's domain. If we had to formalise this, one option is to do what I did in the above proof, another is to assume that $f$ is the restriction of a function on the larger domain, which satisfies some properties (in your case, you essentially assumed $f$ was the restriction of the function $g$ which I defined). If you proceed via the latter method, then you are correct that you need to justify that it doesn't matter what $f$ is a restriction of, which you do argue in your last paragraph

That is very helpful and I do realize now that my assumption was unsound. Thank you!
